# ubuntu 15.10 available in the netherlands?

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

i have a problem with upgrading. my pc won't detect ubuntu 15.10 now i have checked for updates and my pc says: ubuntu 15.04 is available. you have 14.04 meanwile it is begin december 2015 and my pc won't detect ubuntu 15.10. is it true that canonical delivers the latest ubuntu a few month's later for another countries like the netherlands?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the issue is with your being in the Netherlands. :)

Like Dustin Wortman said, you can't skip a version of Ubuntu when you do upgrades. If you want to upgrade from 14.04 you will first have to upgrade to 14.10, then to 15.04, and then to 15.10. To be able to do this you will have to switch your upgrade to 'For any new version' in Settings. (Settings > Software & Updates > Updates)

[image]

But if you are currently ok with your **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** installation, you can wait for the next LTS (Long Term Support) version, which will be **16.04**. This way you can skip these non-LTS versions (14.10, 15.04, 15.10) and enjoy the LTS versions, which generally are more focused on being stable.

More information on LTS Versions: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

Answer (score 0):

A distro upgrade is only possible from one LTS to next LTS version of Ubuntu and from one version, say 15.04 to the directly next, so 15.10.
You have to upgrade to 15.04 and then to 15.10 or reinstall.